# Latest unobtrusive-ajax CDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cdn

I need to upgrade Wijmo (a jQuery lib.). First I have to upgrade jquery with:

**jQuery CDN:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">/script>
```

This new jquery breaks my jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js.

**My old unobtrusive-ajax.js**

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")?ver=@HttpContext.Current.Application["Version"].ToString()" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is their a CDN for the lastest unobtrusive-ajax? I know I can download a .js, but I would prefer the CDN while I'm testing. I've tried googled it, but no luck.

Comment: Concatenate and minify your assets better.

Comment: use nuget package manager - they're all in there